# Access to Facebook users "INTERESTS" lists

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm creating new iOS app with Facebook API. I need to receive posts from user's "INTERESTS" lists.

[image: INTERESTS on Facebook page]

But I can't access it. Graph API from path: "my/friendslist" doesn't actually return this list of "INTERESTS".
I'm sure I can access it, cause I can get info from this list by it's ID. 
Graph API returns this:

```
{
  "id": "MY_COOL_ID", 
  "name": "=3", 
  "list_type": "user_created"
}
```

But I can't figure out how. Any ideas?

Thanks.